# Using .gitignore with Rider IDE

Tags: git, gitignore, rider

How can I add `.gitignore` to my solution in Rider? When I right click on my solution under New, I cannot see anything related to adding `.gitignore` file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That functionality isn't included by default; you can just make a new file named `.gitignore`.

However, there is an excellent `.ignore` plugin available for all JetBrains IDE's:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495--ignore

Answer (score -2):

You need to switch to "File System" view