# Git changes showing all generated files that do not need to be committed

Tags: git, rider

I have a C# project that I pulled onto a new machine, even with no changes made by me, Rider is showing 856 files changed. They all seem to be auto generated to run on my machine, how can I disable this as it makes it difficult to keep track of my actual changes.

[image: rider change window showing all of the generated changes]

Comment: You need a .gitignore file. For example, see: [using-gitignore-with-rider-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994014/using-gitignore-with-rider-ide) Or just google *C# gitignore ryder* for other suggestions/sample gitignore files.

Comment: https://gitignore.io/ coukd help also. Search for "visual studio"

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a .NET project you can use `dotnet new gitignore` command in the root folder of your repo.

This will create a `.gitignore` file which yous should commit to your repo.

If you examine the created file you will be able to see the line that will make you `obj` folders ignored by git:

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
...
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
```

You could also just download https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet/blob/main/.gitignore into your repo.

---

Please note that, if you already committed some of the auto-generated files you would have to delete them manually even if they match the filters in `.gitignore`.